# Android Studio how to debug w/o external device

Tags: android, android-studio

I'd try to make some test on Android Studio, but I don't wont make disaster in my Android phone.
Can I Debug my trials without a device connected? How can I start debug directly to my monitor? Is it possible?
Everytime I run "Debug app", Android Studio seems to search an external device

Comment: Set up an AVD. BTW - no disaster occurs using your device. The emulator will make disaster of your patience.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you should use AVD to debug.

Debugging requires a live device (could be a physical device  or virtual device). You can't do debugging without a device.